# Wordpress website hacked - index.php file modified

Tags: htaccess

My website has been hacked, that is when I click any page its redirect to home page. Unbale to open wp-admin as well. I checked the server, it seems root folder index.php file has been modified with some strange code. Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How was my WP site hacked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26320/how-was-my-wp-site-hacked)

Answer (score 0):

The stupidest and fastest way, if you have a source code backup, delete all the previous files and re-upload the backup file.